# go install c shared output path

Tags: go, installation, shared-libraries, shared

i'm trying to install a library inside a package. However I don't understand where it compiles to.

Structure is like so:
package/cmd/library

I can install other executable targets fine with go install. My paths are set correctly. However now I want to build my shared library target and deploy it somewhere (this deployment step can be done manually). I'm running into two different issues.

Issue one, I can't seem to install it at all:

`go install -buildmode=c-shared bpackage/cmd/library@latest`

Returns with:

```
go install: no install location for directory /home/tpm/go/pkg/mod/package/cmd/library outside GOPATH
        For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

which tells me that it installs somewhere other than in my gopath, I'm just not sure where that might be.

Issue 2, using the -o flag doesn't work with go install, so I can't seem to alter the output location to place it inside the GOPATH (i did try setting the GOBIN to within my gopath, but since other commands work fine I don't think this should be causing any issue)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Ian from https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24253

> Note that it doesn't make a great deal of sense to use `go install -buildmode=c-shared`. The expectation is that people will use `go build -buildmode=c-shared -o foo.so`. The only point of using `-buildmode=c-shared` is to use the shared library somewhere, and using `go install` without `-o` will put the shared library in a relatively unpredictable place.